# How to use new file which is created by me as an output file in FFmpeg code execution ? getting E/mobile-ffmpeg: outputFile.mp3 Permission denied

Tags: java, android-studio, mp3, android-ffmpeg, mobile-ffmpeg

I try to trimming audio from one file to another output file but I am getting trouble accessing the output file in FFmpeg to writing its shows me permission denied.

```
    Metadata:
      title           : 
/home/daytanhisu/public_html/skyitech/../siteuploads/thumb/sft6/thumb_2703.jpg
      comment         : 
Cover (front)

 E/mobile-ffmpeg: /storage/emulated/0/slowmotion.mp3: **Permission denied**
```